# IIS anonymous authentication issue in Microsoft Search Server Express

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, search-server

I am setting up Windows Search Server Express on Windows Server 2008. Here is Windows Search Server Express information. By default, it is using Windows authentication which needs server local Windows user name and account when access the search service from a remote machine.

http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/serverproducts/searchserverexpress/try-1.aspx

My question is, I have tried very hard to make it use anonymous authentication -- i.e. I want all users from other machines be able to access search service without input any user name and password. Any solutions? Any special things of Windows Search Server to make anonymous access?

BTW: if this forum is not appropriate for this question, any recommended forums are appreciated.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding Authenticated Users to the access group and added the search site to the Intranet Zone?

This should allow everyone with an authenticated ticket to access the service with their logged in domain details, and adding it to the Intranet Zone will ensure the ticket is passed behind the scenes.

Comment: Hi Diago, sorry I am not in a Windows domain, just a LAN (intranet). Any advice for my solution? I do not want to let all users to input user name and password before they could issue a query. :-)

Comment: I have never tried to install the Search Server without a Domain. However you will have to create every user with the same username and password on the server, and this should work if you make them part of the group.

Comment: Hi Diago, I am confused. Why I need to create so many users? I just want to enable anonymous access to Windows Search Server. Any ideas?